# react-native-smartconfig-2 and Xcode 14.3 installation issue

Tags: xcode, react-native, npm

I’ve installed react-native-smartconfig-2 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-smartconfig-2?activeTab=readme) using npm but ‘react-native link’ failed as link has been depreciated.  Proceeding through the rest of the instructions including manual install all seemed OK except that the header search path needed an extra /.. (I changed $(SRCROOT)/../../react-native/React to $(SRCROOT)/../../../react-native/React).  However, when I run the project in Xcode I know get this -

[image]

This appears to be due to RCTBridgeModule, and many other header files having import statements like this - #import <React/RCTDefines.h>

I’m sure there’s just a path or symbolic link missing somewhere but I can’t figure it out.

Comment: The library is not maintained https://github.com/tuanpmt/react-native-smartconfig/issues/6

Comment: Is there any React Native library for SmartConfig that is maintained?  I don't seem to be able to find one.